# validation with javascript & xml

Tags: javascript, xml

I am attempting to compare the input text to an xml tag for validation purposes and Im having some trouble.  My error is with the conditional in the calling() function (i think):

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","userPass.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

function calling(){
    if(document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML==
      (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("user")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue){
             alert("this is valid");
  }
}

<form name="input" action="userPass.xml" method="post">
        username <input type="text" id="userName" onchange="calling()" /><br/><br/>
        password <input type="password" id="password"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Thanks for taking the time to help-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a closing parenthesis in the condition for the if statement. Also, you may want to test the value property of the input instead of innerHTML. Your function should look like this:

```
function calling() {
    if (document.getElementById("userName").value == (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("user")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue){ 
       alert("this is valid");
  }
}
```

This is my guess. I can't help you any further without knowing what kind of problems you are running into or what the response from the server looks like.